# How to get this output using SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need help with this.

I have this table of data for illustration. (There are many other rows of data with different customer. Do consider this in the answer)

```
RowID   Customer     Category     Date       Figure1
  1     Cust1        Week 1       Jun-11     10
  2     Cust1        Week 2       Jun-11     20
  3     Cust1        Week 3       Jun-11     30
  4     Cust1        Week 4       Jun-11     40
  5     Cust1        Actual       Jun-11     200
  6     Cust1        Forecast     Jun-11     100
  7     Cust2        Forecast     Jun-11     100
```

I would like to have it display the Category `Actual` only (row 5) including the `RowID` on the pivoted Category as shown below

This should be the output.

```
RowID   Customer Date     Week1  Week2  Week3   Week4   Actual  Forecast
   5    Cust1    Jun-11   10     20     30      40      200     100
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Tried Pivot but it gives me this which is not i want.

```
RowID   Customer Date     Week1  Week2  Week3   Week4   Actual  Forecast
   1    Cust1    Jun-11   10     null   null    null    null    null
   2    Cust1    Jun-11   null   20     null    null    null    null
   3    Cust1    Jun-11   null   null   30      null    null    null
   4    Cust1    Jun-11   null   null   null    40      null    null
   5    Cust1    Jun-11   null   null   null    null    200     null
   6    Cust1    Jun-11   null   null   null    null    null    100
```

Comment: Have you tried the pivot cmd? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: use pivot tables http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx    and http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx

Comment: I have added the results of pivoted. Added in above question. But that is not what i want. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`PIVOT` is fine, but you need to `GROUP BY` and `SUM` afterwards.

Alternatively, you can self-JOIN on all the different code criteria, but it can be slightly less-maintainable than having the list of values in one place like you can with PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
    SELECT
        RowID,
        Customer,
        Date,
        (SELECT Figure1 FROM sotest WHERE Customer = 'Cust1' AND Date = 'Jun-11' AND Category = 'Week 1') AS Week1,
        (SELECT Figure1 FROM sotest WHERE Customer = 'Cust1' AND Date = 'Jun-11' AND Category = 'Week 2') AS Week2,
        (SELECT Figure1 FROM sotest WHERE Customer = 'Cust1' AND Date = 'Jun-11' AND Category = 'Week 3') AS Week3,
        (SELECT Figure1 FROM sotest WHERE Customer = 'Cust1' AND Date = 'Jun-11' AND Category = 'Week 4') AS Week4,
        (SELECT Figure1 FROM sotest WHERE Customer = 'Cust1' AND Date = 'Jun-11' AND Category = 'Actual') AS Actual,
        (SELECT Figure1 FROM sotest WHERE Customer = 'Cust1' AND Date = 'Jun-11' AND Category = 'Forecast') AS Forecast

    FROM
        sotest

    WHERE
        Customer = 'Cust1'
        AND Date = 'Jun-11'
        AND Category = 'Actual'
```

Should be fairly easy to wrap up in a stored procedure, where you can pass the CustomerID and Date params in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution based on two parameters (`@MyCustomer` & `@MyDate`):

```
DECLARE @MyCustomer VARCHAR(10) = 'Cust1'
    ,@MyDate VARCHAR(10) = 'Jun-11';

SELECT pvt.*
FROM
(
SELECT  t.Customer, t.Date, t.Category, t.Figure1
FROM    MyTable t
WHERE   t.Customer = @MyCustomer AND t.[Date] = @MyDaye
) src
PIVOT ( SUM(src.Figure1) FOR src.Category IN ([Week 1], [Week 2], [Week 3], [Week 4], [Actual], [Forecast]) ) pvt
```

*The basic idea is to filter in `src` derived table only those rows and columns you need for pivot, nothing more or less.*